# Using .net 3.5 dll in .net 2.0 app. No config file was found, error?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I make .net 3.5 class library project which has service reference to web servis. And use this xx.dll along with its xx.dll.config successfully in my .net 3.5 app.
But, now I want to use it with my .net 2.0 application, more precise in one windows form of my .net 2.0 app. But I got this error:
"..This maight be beacuse no configuration file was found for your application.."
I guess I must include appropriate dll.config file in my .net 2.0 app.
Here is the contents of my config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="RzzoServicePortBinding">
                    <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="TripleDes" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
                        requireDerivedKeys="true" securityHeaderLayout="Lax" includeTimestamp="false">
                        <localClientSettings detectReplays="false" />
                        <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" />
                    </security>
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
                    <httpsTransport />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://webapp2.rzzo.rs:443/rzzo/RzzoService"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="RzzoServicePortBinding"
                contract="ServiceReference1.RzzoService" name="RzzoServicePort" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

How can I do this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty certain that config file won't work in .NET 2.0, as things such as endpoint address etc are WCF concepts and only for .NET 3 and above.

Comment: If I can't use it with .net 2.0 I must make .net 2.0 .dll which consumes web service. I try to do that (make serviceClass with wsdl.exe and add web reference) but I always got this error: "Security requirement not met - No security header in message"?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't upgrade your .NET 2.0 application to 3.5?

Comment: My boss thinks it's a tough job. Because the application is large! :-)

Comment: Go into project->properties, select Application and change the target framework to 3.5.  Recompile and that basically should be it.  You can get problems going back from say 3.5 to 2.0, but I've never had any problems going the other way.....